# Cant build my unity project. "The type or namespace name 'Speech' does not exist in the namespace"; What can I do to fix? (VR Unity)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, error-handling, virtual-reality

I have a problem to build my unity project. I have a VR unity project I want to build to use my oculus quest 2 to test my game. But when building I get 5 errors for a class of mine. I dont really know what I did wrong and the error message isnt much helping. Please help me!

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGSmZ.png)

[first error in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVq0f.png)

[second error in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGKza.png)

[third error in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykyeS.png)

[fourth error in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhRz3.png)

I couldnt do much, because in the code, the lines arent even red and I can run the project without much issue.
The errors occur if I want to build the game, but not if I just run it.
I want to build the game so i can interact with it with the oculus quest 2.

Comment: Do not post pictures of errors. Post the error text.

Comment: Well. The input system maybe because you arent using the new input system. But without the minimal viable example. Always deal with the first error first. Try limit your post to 1 question the others no idea whats wrong with them as theres no hint which line or what error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use something else to detect speech.
You can not use UnityEngine.**Windows**.Speech on Android platform. It does not exist like the error describes.

Comment: Is there a other way then to use a oculus quest? I got this project from my professor and I did a study on this in VR. I wanted to build the project on android because I read these VR glasses are seen as android devices.

Comment: They are Android devices but you cannot use the Windows speech input on them. That would only work on HoloLens. If that is a university project you need to look at your requirements. Do you want to release for Quest or do you want to proof a concept? Ich you want to use the Quest autonomously you need to use another speech recognition. I think the Oculues SDK includes one. Or you create a Windows app instead and use the Quest with Oculus Link.